# Eclipse Oxygen does not mark occurrences - How to fix?

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-pdt

I have set up Eclipse Oxygen.1 4.7.1 (Build 20170914-1200) to work on a Symfony based PHP project.

Everything works fine but the highlight of occurrences (e.g. local variables, methods, etc.).

```
public function someMethod($paramA) {
    doSomething($paramA);
    ...
    $var = $paramA;
}
```

When I place the cursor within `$paramA` in the method signature, I would expect, that the occurrences of `$paramA` within the method body are highlighted. This was definitely the case when using Ecplise Mars some time ago. Any idea why this does not work?

I already checked `Preferences/PHP/Editor/Mark/Occurrences` where all options are checked/activated.

`Preferences/General/Editors/Text Editors/Annotations/Occurrences` seems to be setup correct as well (Vertical ruler: No, Overview ruler: Yes, Text as Highlight, Color: Grey, Includ in next/previous navigation: No)

Are there any other preferences which need to be checked?

This is the list of installed software:

```
Eclipse GitHub integration with task focused interface  4.8.0.201706111038-r    org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature.feature.group Eclipse EGit
Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers  4.7.1.20170914-1200 epp.package.php Eclipse Packaging Project
Eclipse Platform    4.7.1.v20170906-1700    org.eclipse.platform.feature.group  Eclipse.org
Eclipse RCP 4.7.1.v20170906-1700    org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group   Eclipse.org
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools   3.9.1.v201707252002 org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Git integration for Eclipse 4.8.0.201706111038-r    org.eclipse.egit.feature.group  Eclipse EGit
Git integration for Eclipse - Gitflow support   4.8.0.201706111038-r    org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.feature.feature.group  Eclipse EGit
Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface    4.8.0.201706111038-r    org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group    Eclipse EGit
JavaScript Development Tools    2.1.0.v201706011953 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
Mylyn Context Connector: Eclipse IDE    3.23.0.v20170411-2108   org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
Mylyn Task List 3.23.1.v20170623-0008   org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
Mylyn Task-Focused Interface    3.23.0.v20170414-0629   org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
Mylyn Tasks Connector: Bugzilla 3.23.1.v20170623-0008   org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
Mylyn WikiText  3.0.6.201703111926  org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
Oomph Setup 1.9.0.v20170706-0615    org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group   Eclipse Oomph Project
PDT Extensions  0.23.1.201707041945 org.pdtextensions.feature.feature.group http://pdt-extensions.org
PHP CodeSniffer 1.3.0.R20111119000000   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.codesniffer.feature.group  Sven Kiera
PHP Copy/Paste Detection    0.2.2.R20100414000000   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpcpd.feature.group   Sven Kiera
PHP Depend  0.3.3.R20110627000000   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpdepend.feature.group    Sven Kiera
PHP Development Tools (PDT) 5.2.0.201709191002  org.eclipse.php.feature.group   Eclipse PDT
PHP Development Tools (PDT) Composer Support    5.2.0.201709191002  org.eclipse.php.composer.feature.group  Eclipse PDT
PHP Development Tools (PDT) Mylyn Integration   5.2.0.201709191002  org.eclipse.php.mylyn.feature.group Eclipse PDT
PHP Development Tools (PDT) PHPUnit Support 5.2.0.201709191002  org.eclipse.php.phpunit.feature.feature.group   Eclipse PDT
PHP Development Tools (PDT) Remote Project Synchronization Support  5.2.0.201709191002  org.eclipse.php.rdt.sync.feature.group  Eclipse PDT
PHP Development Tools (PDT) Zend Profiler Support   5.2.0.201709191002  org.eclipse.php.profiler.feature.group  Eclipse PDT
PHP Mess Detector   0.1.0.R20110628000000   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpmd.feature.group    Dejan Spasic
PHP Tool Integration Core   1.6.0.R20111119000000   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.core.feature.group   Sven Kiera
PHPUnit 0.8.0.R20111119000000   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpunit.feature.group  Sven Kiera
Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime 3.7.3.201704251225  org.eclipse.rse.feature.group   Eclipse TM Project
Smarty Feature  0.10.0.201707132003 org.eclipse.php.smarty_feature.feature.group    null
TM Terminal 4.3.0.201706140544  org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - Target Management
Twig Editor Feature 2.1.1.201707041935  com.dubture.twig.feature.feature.group  https://github.com/pulse00
YEdit Feature   1.0.20.201509041456-RELEASE org.dadacoalition.yedit.feature.feature.group   YEdit Project
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at the beginning. Maybe it's your folder or project structure?

Mark concurrency does not work with me if the script was added via "Open Projects from File System ...".

Try to create "PHP Project" in Eclipse with the same name as your project. Then drag your scripts or even the whole folder structure into the newly created project, update with "Refresh" and the highlighting should work.

Comment: I do not use any project. The files are not stored on the locale machine but on a remove server. Thus there is no project folder, meta-data file, etc. on my local machine. The remove files are accessed using the Remote System Explorer, and this are "normal" files without any Eclipse Project Structure.

Comment: I have the suspicion the problem could be similar. By working with github, the files are somehow incorrectly read in eclipse that the mark does not work properly.

Comment: If you have the same issue as I have, the Code Sniffer plugin is not working with the latest version of Eclipse. IF you try to edit the options, it will throw a lot of exceptions.